# Is there API to get someone's facebook profile with out login to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I was wondering if its possible to get one's facebook profile (to be exact,'profile url') through their API?

I need an api to get fb profile link using a matching email address. I dont want to login to facebook though.I was trying to search for this but it seems you need to log in to facebook to get that.

Any idea or is it feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **ID** of the concerned user which can't be achieved without using the **Facebook Login**, since Facebook login is the starting point to get the current user info (`/me`).

[Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search) could have helped you since you have the email ids of users, but unfortunately this api doesn't support user search with email!

So, answer is simple- **NO**, you cannot get the ID (profile link) of the user without using the facebook login.

Comment: Thank you sahil for your answe. But you know I found an API provider which is providing such functionality. I have very limited knowledge of the whole arena still i was wondering if facebook does not support this how come this provider can get the data? Here is the provider which is a paid service https://www.fullcontact.com/ . Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure of that service. But it seems impossible to me

Answer (score 0):

Not that I can think of.  Facebook's Graph API gives you some public info but that info given depends on the users Facebook's settings on what is public or not.  You could maybe get some users profile picture but not others, making it not a very viable option for practical use.  Hope that helps